# LibGDX: How to draw a transparent Polygon?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm currently using `ShapeRenderer` to draw polygons.

**Code:**

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
shapeRenderer.setColor(255 / 255.0f, 109 / 255.0f, 120 / 255.0f, 0.0f);

Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
//drawing a sample rectangle to test transparency(it worked)
shapeRenderer.rect(getRect().x, getRect().y,
                    getRect().width, getRect().height);
//drawing polygon
shapeRenderer.polygon(getPoly().getTransformedVertices());
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);

shapeRenderer.end();
```

I'm getting the rectangle as a transparent one but polygon is still opaque as ever.

How to do this correctly?
Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual "drawing" probably isn't happening until the `shapeRenderer.end()` call.  Try moving that up:

```
//drawing polygon
shapeRenderer.polygon(getPoly().getTransformedVertices());
shapeRenderer.end();

Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
```